# Can't delete in Mysql saying incorrect integer value when it is correct

Tags: mysql

I was trying to delete rows in a Mysql table as shown in the image below. it keeps telling me the integer value is incorrect when it is a correct integer value. Look like it reads another column as the requested integer column. Is this a Mysql bug? Do I need to do some settings in Mysql?

[image: Mysql workbench result]

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: Yes, there is one after delete

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER 
    customer_BEFORE_DELETE BEFORE DELETE ON customer FOR EACH 
    ROW BEGIN
    replace into customer_copy select customer.* from database_1.customer 
    where customer.id=old.id;
 

  
  
 END

Comment: That’s probably what’s failing then.  What is customer_copy?  Do it’s columns exactly line up with customer?  The error implies they don’t.

Comment: @David, Hi David, thank you very much that is exactly the problem. After deleting the trigger. All good.  Thank you very much.